# coc-pairs not working

Tags: neovim, plugin-coc

I've followed the instructions at https://github.com/neoclide/coc-pairs to install the autopair extension for coc:

`:CocInstall coc-pairs`

After running this command, I get the following message:

```
Install finished                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   │~
    - ✓ coc-pairs Move extension coc-pairs@1.4.1 to /Users/adamgyarmati/.config/coc/extensions/node_modules/coc-pairs
```

The extension shows up if I run `:CocList extensions` and the package is listed in `.config/coc/extensions/package.json`. However if I open any file and type `(` or `"`, nothing happens, the parentheses / quotes aren't closed.

I've noticed that after installing the extension, if I run `:CocConfig`, none of the options mentioned in the documentation are there. I've tried manually adding  `"pairs.enableCharacters": ["(", "[", "{", "<", "'", "\""]` but that didn't help either.

I'm using nvim v0.5.1 and I don't have any other autopair plugin installed (at least not that I know of).

Any idea what could cause this issue and how to debug it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can reproduce the problem on:

- Neovim 0.6.1
- Neovim 0.7.0

It works on Neovim 0.8.0

It seems that you need a more recent version of Neovim: version >= 0.8

Comment: Thanks, I'll try this. I didn't find a version requirement for Neovim, the docs say `Ensure your Vim version >= 8.0 using :version`

Comment: Yepp, upgrading neovim worked, thanks! I was worried about upgrading but just ran `brew upgrade neovim` and nothing broke.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback :-)